# Convert Tensorflow graph to CoreML

Tags: metal, coreml, coremltools

I'm trying to convert a Tensorflow graph to CoreML and I'm following [this tutorial](http://machinethink.net/blog/coreml-custom-layers/). There's this bit of code that I don't quite understand:

```c
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void swish(
  texture2d_array<half, access::read> inTexture [[texture(0)]],
  texture2d_array<half, access::write> outTexture [[texture(1)]],
  ushort3 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
  if (gid.x >= outTexture.get_width() || 
      gid.y >= outTexture.get_height()) {
    return;
  }

  const float4 x = float4(inTexture.read(gid.xy, gid.z));
  const float4 y = x / (1.0f + exp(-x));             
  outTexture.write(half4(y), gid.xy, gid.z);
}
```

What I don't understand is the use of `gid` here. Isn't the grid 2 dimensional? What does `gid.z` signify? Isn't `gid.x` is the current x-coordinate of the current pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gid.x` and `gid.y` are the x/y coordinate of the current pixel. So when you do a `texture.read(gid.xy)` it gives you 4 channels worth of pixel data.

But the "images" used in neural networks may have many more than 4 channels. That's why the data type for the textures is `texture2d_array<>` instead of just `texture2d<>`.

The `gid.z` value refers to the index of the texture "slice" in this array. If the image/tensor has 32 channels, then there are 8 texture slices (because each texture stores up to 4 channels of data).

So the grid really is three dimensional: (x, y, slice).

Comment: Can I ask a few more questions? What exactly is the value of `gid` when `swish(..)` is called? Is it an arbitrary coordinate on the input image in no particular order? As the whole image will need to be 'scanned', what ensures that the whole image is processed?

Comment: That's taken care of by the line `encoder.dispatch(pipeline: swishPipeline, texture: inputs[i])`. This is an extension on `MTLComputeCommandEncoder`. It schedules one thread for each pixel in each texture slice.